# ES6 Generators: input value for .next()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm following this [awesome blog](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-generators-in-depth) and there is a simple example of generators with sending a value for the `.next()` method:

```
var answers = [
  `It is certain`, `It is decidedly so`, `Without a doubt`,
  `Yes definitely`, `You may rely on it`, `As I see it, yes`,
  `Most likely`, `Outlook good`, `Yes`, `Signs point to yes`,
  `Reply hazy try again`, `Ask again later`, `Better not tell you now`,
  `Cannot predict now`, `Concentrate and ask again`,
  `Don't count on it`, `My reply is no`, `My sources say no`,
  `Outlook not so good`, `Very doubtful`
]
function answer () {
  return answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)]
}

// The most relevant part
function* chat () {
  while (true) {
    let question = yield '[Genie] ' + answer()
    console.log(question)
  }
}
```

I really can't understand how this input will produce this output:

```
var g = chat()
g.next()
console.log(g.next('[Me] Will ES6 die a painful death?').value)
// <- '[Me] Will ES6 die a painful death?'
// <- '[Genie] My sources say no'
```

Where does the first output comes from - the [Me] part of the result?

Comment: Well, what you pass into `next(…)` is the result of the `yield` expression and will become the `question`, which is logged before the next encounter with a `yield` causes the `next` call to return.

Comment: But isn't the question is overridden  when I call the .next() method? 
I cant see why both of the output will be printed out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "overridden". One of the outputs comes from `question` (in the generator function), the other from `g.next(…).value` (outside of the generator).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression after `yield` will go out(returned).   The value passed to `next()` goes in, and the `yield` expression evaluates to this value. Note though any value passed in on the first .next() call is thrown away and not used.

1. `g.next()` is called

   ```
   let question = yield '[Genie] ' + answer()    
                        ^-------------------^
         execution is paused here, this expression is evaluated
         and the result will go out(returned)
              {value:"[Genie] ...",done:false}
   ```
2. Then `g.next('[Me] Will ES6 die a painful death?')` is called

   ```
   g.next('[Me] Will ES6 die a painful death?').value
          ^----------------------------------^
    string goes in, execution continues, yield expression 
         will be evaluated as the passed in string

    let question = yield '[Genie] ' + answer(); //becomes -v
    let question = '[Me] Will ES6 die a painful death?';
   ```
3. `question` equals the `[Me]` string
4. `question` gets logged to console by `console.log(question)`
5. Execution continues until the next yield is encountered

   ```
   let question = yield '[Genie] ' + answer()    
                        ^-------------------^
         execution is paused here, this expression is evaluated
         and the result will go out(returned)
              {value:"[Genie] ...",done:false}
   ```
6. Now `g.next('[Me] Will ES6 die a painful death?')` evaluates to

   ```
   {value:"[Genie] ...",done:false}
   ```

   Making the last line evaluating as such:

   ```
   console.log( g.next('[Me] Will ES6 die a painful death?').value );
   //becomes 
   console.log( ({value:"[Genie] ...",done:false}).value );
   //which becomes
   console.log("[Genie] ...");
   ```

Answer (score 1):

What cleared a lot of confusion about this for me was the [MDN documentation for yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield).

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> [rv] = yield [expression];
> ```
>
> #### rv
>
> Returns the optional value passed to the generator's next() method to resume its execution.

That's why it's the **second** call to `next` that will determine the value of `let question`. That's where we *resume* the execution.

The generator then prints out the question, continues to the next round of the loop, yields the next Genie's answer and halts. If there would be yet another call to `next`, the argument passed to that would determine the next value of `let question`.